# To classify custom classes (Basically classify types of icecream) in ResNet50 Keras

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, resnet

Resnet50 is cool when we need classify different objects, say tree, dogs, tampons etc. But what if we want further classify say types of trees, or icecreams(Cone, candystick, cup) using ResNet50. Is there a way this would work? PyTorch answers are also welcome.

Comment: There's at least two ways to do this, 1. simply increasing the number of classes and 2. doing multilevel classification

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

ResNet50 is just an architecture of a artificial neural network. What you want to classify depends on the training data you feed it or the data it was trained on if you use pretrained weights.

If you want to classify types of trees, you would need to create (or find) a data set that show different type of trees with the appropriate label. Then you can train on the different tree types.

I suggest that you go through some tutorials, as explaining the whole process of data collection, data preprocessing, data annotation, and training an ANN or classic machine learning models would be a bit much here.

Best of luck